# Is there a specific standard error for an individual residual?

Tags: regression, residuals, standard-error, leverage

On page 97 of Introduction to Statistical Learning book, there is a paragraph on studentized residuals within the context of looking for outliers.

> But in practice, it can be difficult to decide how large a residual
>   needs to be before we consider the point to be an outlier. To address
>   this problem, instead of plotting the residuals, we can plot the
>   studentized residuals, computed by dividing each residual *e*<sub>i</sub> by its estimated standard error.

This gist of this makes sense, I understand that we are looking for residuals that are more than 2-3 deviations away from the mean.

What confused me was use of the word "its"

> in each residual *e*<sub>i</sub> by its estimated standard error

This implies there is a standard error for each residual *e*<sub>i</sub> as opposed to a standard error for all of the residuals as a group. Have I misread or misunderstood this?

When calculating studentized residuals am I dividing each residual by the regression RSE or some other denominator?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/206566/calculate-the-internally-studentized-residual

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, at least for linear regression, so I will answer for that case. The model is then
$$
    Y=X\beta+\epsilon
$$
in matrix form, where $Y$ is $n\times 1$, $X$ is $n\times p$, $\beta$ is $p\times 1$ and the error term $\epsilon$ is $n\times 1$. We assume the errors $\epsilon_i$ are iid with variance $\sigma^2$ (and expectation zero).

Then the least squares estimator is $\hat{\beta}=(X^T X)^{-1}X^T Y$ and the predicted values is $\hat{Y}= X\hat{\beta}=X (X^TX)^{-1} X^T Y= H Y$ where $H= X (X^TX)^{-1} X^T$ is the hat matrix. The residual vector $r= Y-\hat{Y}=(I-H)Y$
has expectation zero and variance matrix $\text{Var}(r)= (I-H) \sigma^2 I (I-H)  = \sigma^2 (I-H)$ so the standard error of residual component $i$ is
$$
  \text{se}(r_i) = \sigma \sqrt{1-h_i}
$$
and we can show that $ 0\le h_i \le 1$.  $h_i$ is often seen as a measure of the *influence* or *leverage* of observation $i$, so we can see that the most influential observations have residuals with lesser standard error.